# <textarea> wrap is not working after including event.keycode == 13 in my html

Tags: javascript, html

I included the below code that is included in ** (bold) in my HTML form. I also have  tags in my html form. After including the code in bold, enter key is not working in  tag.

```
<form name="linemanagerdb" action="lineManagerDb.jsp" onsubmit="return checkform()" onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;" method="post"> 

    <td>Employee ID</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" value="" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('btnSearch').click()" /></td>
</tr>

<input type="button" value="Search" id="btnSearch">
```

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to do???

Comment: 1. Got a jsfidde? 2. ehich brrowsers have you tried? 3. Please display your javascript. 4. are you using any css?

Comment: And also your markup seems to be wrong. `tr` and `td` need to be in a `table`. And a `td` in a `tr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All we need to do is remove the TextArea tag from within the  Tag. This resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have missing double quote of `onclick`

```
<input type="button" value="Search" onclick="" id="btnSearch">
```

Comment: It didn't resolve the issue. I am still no able to use wrap in textarea.

Comment: EX: <form name="linemanagerdb" action="UserManagement.jsp"  onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;" method="post"> 
<table>
<tr>
        <td>Employee ID</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" value="" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('btnSearch').click()" /></td>
         </tr>
         </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Search"  id="btnSearch" />

<textarea   rows="5" cols="12" name="jDesc"
        id="jDesc"  
         ></textarea>
 <script>
document.getElementById("btnSearch").onclick = function(){  
}  
</script>
</form>

Comment: @Nash Exactly what you have want ? your employeid insert into textarea after enter key press.

Comment: My issue is only text area wrap is not working after including event ==13.

Comment: Ok i understand if you want wrap in textarea so you have to remove this code in your form onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;" because whenever enter is press your form keypress event is fire.

Comment: No because whenever enter key press your form key press event is execute.

Comment: Why you have write keypress function of form?

Comment: I have three divs in my actual form. Search is located in a div and one div holds Submit button with form. Search div contains text box. Now search should get submitted when enter is pressed in text box located under Search div.

Comment: You have write this keycode (onkeydown="return event.keyCode != 13;") event in your search textbox then solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

invalid markup, missed ending double quote `"` in the following:

```
<input type="button" value="Search" onclick=" id="btnSearch">
                                            ^^ Missing ending double quote here
```

It should be:

```
<input type="button" value="Search" onclick="" id="btnSearch">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="linemanagerdb" action="UserManagement.jsp" onkeypress="return checkValue(event)" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Employee ID</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" value="" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('btnSearch').click()"
            />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" id="btnSearch" />
    <textarea class="styled" rows="5" cols="12" name="jDesc" id="jDesc"></textarea>
    <script>
        function checkValue(event) {
            var e = event || window.event;
            var elem = e.target || e.srcElement;

            if (elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'input') {
                return event.keyCode != 13;
            }

            return true;
        }
        document.getElementById("btnSearch").onclick = function () {
            alert("ok")
        }
    </script>
</form>
```

Comment: but I am still unable to wrap text in Textarea tag.

Comment: put a condition for textarea too ****this.nodeName.toLowerCase()=='input'****

Comment: <form name="linemanagerdb" action="UserManagement.jsp"  onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;" method="post"> 
<table>
<tr>
        <td>Employee ID</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" value="" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('btnSearch').click()" /></td>
         </tr>
         </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Search"  id="btnSearch" />

<textarea class="styled" rows="5" cols="12" name="jDesc"
        id="jDesc"  
         ></textarea>
 <script>
document.getElementById("btnSearch").onclick = function(){  
}  
</script>
</form>

Comment: make a conditional function and call it when onkeypress event fire, edited the answer.

Comment: but the main issue is TEXTAREA wrap. If I press enter in TextArea box, then enter functionality is not working. Your code works fine but the enter feature in TextArea not working.

Comment: normally only one functionality can be done, either line break in textarea or trigger submit button when enter key pressed.